# Avoid Postback in Sharepoint webpart using AJax

Tags: sharepoint-2010, asp.net-ajax, asynchronous-postback

I have created a webpart in visual studio 2012 and deployed in Sharepoint server(2013).All code is written in server side.So whenever an event occurs
post back takes place.How can we avoid postback when events occur(eg:button click)
using Ajax.

Comment: Simplest option will be to use UpdatePanel if post back occurs due to the server side controls, for the client side controls you can use JQuery ajax.

Comment: Jatin,My requirement is to avoid postback keeping server side coding intact.Can we achieve using Ajax?

Comment: Hi @Ajith, The postback will still take place even if you use ajax the only difference is that the end user will not notice the refresh of page. Now it depends on what actually you are trying to achieve if JQuery satisfy your needs then you can replace your existing server side code with the JQuery.

Comment: Can you share some info on the server side code you have implemented and what exactly you are trying to achieve in the web part?

Comment: Hi @Jatin   a button event is given below  protected void btncanceldelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            div_delete_container.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none");
        }

Comment: Hi @Ajith, It seems that you are adding styling to the Dom elements. you can easily achieve this with help of JQuery. No server side code and Ajax is required to achieve this. Hope so this helps you.

Comment: Hi @Jatin I will give part of code to delete a file from document library.How can we avoid postback here? protected void btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (strArray[i] == doclib.RootFolder.Url)
                {
                    for (int j = i; j < strArray.Length - 1; j++)
                    {
                        path += strArray[j] + "/";
                        k = j + 1;
                    }
                }
            }}

Comment: You will need to use Javascript and use a Sharepoint client side sharepoint technology like CSOM or REST to do List operations from the client side